# MS SQL Server - All the data in table are not showing while converting Columns to Rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

In **MS SQL Server**, I need to convert a table's one column(column name is Question in my case) data to different column headers and another column(Column name is Answer in my case) data to data of the newly formatted column names ( I searched for answered related to similar questions but there are no answers for my issue hence asked a new question).

SQL Fiddler - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b24f0/3

Table has data as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bac182/1/0

**This is my Query:**

```
;WITH CTE as 

(
select 
EmployeeName,
Date,
Question 'Questions',
Answer 'Scores'
from QA 
where Date= '2020-02-04'
),

CTE2 as (

SELECT Date,EmployeeName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Mother Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Mother Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Father Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Father Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Brother Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Brother Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Sister Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Sister Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Wife Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Wife Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Son Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Son Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Daughter Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Daughter Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Granpa Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Granpa Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Grandma Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Grandma Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Uncle Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Uncle Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Aunt Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Aunt Name]
FROM CTE s
WHERE 
      Questions IN ('What is your Mother Name?',
'What is your Father Name?',
'What is your Brother Name?',
'What is your Sister Name?',
'What is your Wife Name?',
'What is your Son Name?',
'What is your Daughter Name?',
'What is your Grandpa Name?',
'What is your Grandma Name?',
'What is your Uncle Name?',
'What is your Aunt Name?'
)
Group by Date,EmployeeName
)
  Select * from CTE2
```

**This is current result:** (Please click the pic to see it very clear)

[image]

**My expected output is:**(Please click the pic to see it very clear)

[image]

I understood that the query is fetching MAX value of each record so that I'm getting incorrect data. But If I remove MAX from the CTE2, I'm getting more NULL records and not getting correct data. Please help me to fix the issue.

So now I'm getting records for Date, EmployeeName with MAX value but I need all the appropriate records of that Date/EmployeeName even there are multiple records for a same day and EmployeeName

I will provide more details if any one required on top of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combination of (`EmployeeName`, `Date`, `QuestionID`, `Question`) is not unique for `EmployeeName = John`. You need a new column to distinquish between the first set of questions for John and his second set. Then you can group on that new column as well and the `max()` function should work fine.

I added a column `RowNum` to split John's question sets. Your current sample data set contains not enough data to guarantee that this new `RowNum` column will always produce the correct results.

If you have a `QuestionSetId` column somewhere, then this field should replace the new `RowNum` column in the CTE.

```
WITH CTE as (
  select  EmployeeName,
          Date,
          Question as Questions,
          Answer as Scores,
          row_number() over(partition by EmployeeName, Date, QuestionId order by EmployeeName) as RowNum -- define a proper 'order by'... sorting on EmployeeName alone is not guaranteed to give the correct results
  from QA 
  where Date = '2020-02-04'
)
SELECT Date,
       EmployeeName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Mother Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Mother Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Father Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Father Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Brother Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Brother Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Sister Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Sister Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Wife Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Wife Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Son Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Son Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Daughter Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Daughter Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Grandpa Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Grandpa Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Grandma Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Grandma Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Uncle Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Uncle Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Questions = 'What is your Aunt Name?' THEN CAST(Scores as varchar(50)) END) as [Aunt Name]
FROM CTE s
WHERE Questions IN (
  'What is your Mother Name?',
  'What is your Father Name?',
  'What is your Brother Name?',
  'What is your Sister Name?',
  'What is your Wife Name?',
  'What is your Son Name?',
  'What is your Daughter Name?',
  'What is your Grandpa Name?',
  'What is your Grandma Name?',
  'What is your Uncle Name?',
  'What is your Aunt Name?'
)
group by Date,
         EmployeeName,
         RowNum; -- add new column as part of grouping
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a09f/1) (includes some data correction as well).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sander. Yes you are correct, I missed the uniqueID in that table and after using that in grouping I'm getting correct record. :)